# How to Delay MailChimp subscription popup?

Tags: javascript, popup, mailchimp

The free version (below 2000 subscribers) of MailChimp subscription popup allows at most 5 seconds of delay before the pop up window executes. But i want to delay the popup to 45 seconds. Is there any way to make it happen? Thanks in Advance.

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.mailchimp.com/js/signup-forms/popup/embed.js" data-dojo-config="usePlainJson: true, isDebug: false"></script><script type="text/javascript">require(["mojo/signup-forms/Loader"], function(L) { L.start({"baseUrl":"mc.us11.list-manage.com","uuid":"32e8df9557dd399bb3ba2ae61","lid":"6d35f0128b"}) })</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Set a timeout on the call to load it.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.mailchimp.com/js/signup-forms/popup/embed.js" data-dojo-config="usePlainJson: true, isDebug: false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   setTimeout(function(){
                require(["mojo/signup-forms/Loader"], function(L) { L.start({"baseUrl":"mc.us11.list-manage.com","uuid":"32e8df9557dd399bb3ba2ae61","lid":"6d35f0128b"}) })
    }, 45000);
</script>
```